# Python. Create folder if it does not exist. But more complicated

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a python program using the Flask framework, but I have a problem.
I'll explain.
I need to save some images in a directory. So I have to create a directory called Folder, but first I have to check if this directory doesn't already exist.
So I should check if Folder exists, if it doesn't exist I create Folder directory, otherwise I create Folder1 directory.
But in the same way I have to check if Folder1  exists and if it already exists I see for the Folder2 directory and so on ...
After creating the directory I need to always use the same directory to save all the images.
That is, even if I terminate the program, the next time I run it must always save the other images in the directory created.
I ask for your help in doing this, because I don't know how to do it.
I tried to do this, but it doesn't work as it should:

```
path = "path/to/folder"
def create_directory():
global path
if(os.path.isdir(path)==False):
    os.makedirs(path)
else:
    cont=1
    new_path = path
    while(os.path.isdir(new_path)==True):
        new_path = str(path)+str(cont)
        cont= cont +1
   os.makedirs(new_path)
```

Comment: Can you share your code attempt please?

Comment: use `os.makedirs` as in the linked duplicate, with parameter `exist_ok=True`

Comment: perhaps you also need `os.path.exists` into your solution

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code helps:

```
import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/root/directory1"

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Comment: this is half an answer, how would you handle the increasing number suffix?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I just read the question title and jumped into a suggestion.

Comment: Just in a similar way, you can use the ```Path.mkdir``` from ```pathlib``` module. I like that a lot better since it has so many intuitive methods to deal with files and folders and they're very intuitive to use. So in the code above, if you replace ```os``` with ```pathlib``` and replace ```os.mkdir``` with `pathlib.Path.mkdir``` it should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

This can use a number of error handling (in case regex fails, etc) but should get you started on the correct path:

```
import regex
from pathlib import Path

def mkdir(path_str): 
    path = Path(path_str) 
     
    # this while loop ensures you get the next folder name (the correct number appended to the base folder name)
    while path.exists(): 
        s= re.search('(\w+)(\d+)',path.name) 
        base,number = s.groups() 
        new_path_str = base + str(int(number)+1) 
        path = path.parent.joinpath(new_path_str) 
                
    try: 
        path.mkdir() 
        print(f'The directory {path.name} was created!') 
    except OSError: 
        print (f"Creation of the directory {path} failed")
```